# What does the keyword this mean in C#, when talking about event handlers?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

When I write an event handler for csharp, it looks like this:

```
public void FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff..
    this.doSomething();  //Does the "this" keyword mean something in this context?
}
```

Does the "this" keyword mean something in this context?

EDIT:

Let's say I also have this code:

```
public class GizmoManager {
    public void Manage() {
        g = new Gizmo();
        g.Foo += new EventHandler(FooHandler);
    }
}
```

What would the `this` (within `FooHandler`) refer to?

Comment: `this` keyword is not alone on the line right?

Comment: Yes, `this` would refer to `g` in your `Gizmo` class only. `sender` would refer to the class calling the `EventHandler`.

Comment: Leito, I currently have two contradictory answers. Read @loki's answer since he clarifies more than me, and see if you still say the same thing.

Comment: Contradictory because I don't think we were speaking about the same `this`. If you keep editing your question and change the code everytime, it's a bit difficult to follow and comments become obsolete :). In your example, `this` refers to the class that owns `FooHandler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a reference to object for which `FooHandler()` is called. Delegates are capable of referencing both static and non-static methods. When talking about non-static ones, `this` is a reference to object instance.

```
class A
{
   public delegate void MyDelegate(object sender, int x);
   public event MyDelegate TheEvent;

   public void func()
   {
     if(TheEvent != null) TheEvent(this, 123);
   }
}

class B
{
   public B()
   {
     A a = new A();
     a.TheEvent += handler;
     a.func();
   }

   public void handler(object sender, int x)
   {
      // "sender" is a reference to object of type A that we've created in ctor
      // "x" is 123
      // "this" is a reference to B (b below)
   } 
}

B b = new B(); // here it starts
```

Some more details. Your code:

```
g = new Gizmo();
g.Foo += new EventHandler(FooHandler);
```

could be re-written like this

```
g = new Gizmo();
g.Foo += new EventHandler(this.FooHandler); // look here
```

In this case `this` is the same `this` that you have in your handler ;-)

And even more, if you have some problems with understanding `this`:

```
class X
{
  int a;

  public X(int b)
  {
    this.a = b; // this stands for "this object"
    // a = b is absolutely the same
  }

  public X getItsThis()
  {
    return this;
  }
}

X x = new X();
X x2 = x.getItsThis();
// x and x2 refer to THE SAME object
// there's still only one object of class X, but 2 references: x and x2
```

Comment: ummm, I'm not trying to complicate things, but if `this` refers to `b` in your example, then in my question, `this` would _not_ refer to `g` correct? Because `g` in my example is the same as `a` in yours (not `b`) correct?

Comment: In you example, `FooHandler()` is non-static method. That means, that this method is always called against **object** of some class. `this` refers to this object. So, in your case, `this` would refer to the object that you have your `g = new Gizmo();
g.Foo += new EventHandler(FooHandler);` code executed against. That would be much easier to answer if you provide some more context.

Comment: @Thr4wn `this` used in the `handler` method refers to `b` here because `handler` is owned by `B`.

Comment: I think I finally understand! :) sorry for the original lack of full context.

Answer (score 2):

more complete...

```
public class Bar
{
  public Bar()
  {
    Gizmo g = new Gizmo();
    g.Foo += new EventHandler(FooHandler);

  }

  public void FooHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //do stuff..
    this  //Does the "this" keyword mean something in this context?
  }
}
```

"this" will refer to an instance of Bar

Comment: ahh. That makes sense. Would `sender` be `g` instance in this case?

Comment: Yes, sender would refer to the ojbect that "fired" the event, most likely an instance of g

Comment: I would suggest, for clarity's sake, that you rename the class `Foo` at the top to be `Bar` to make sure that it's clear that this class has nothing to do with the `Foo` event defined somewhere else within `Gizmo`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is going to refer to the current class you are in, not the method.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx),

> The this keyword refers to the current instance of the class. Static
>   member functions do not have a this pointer. The this keyword can be
>   used to access members from within constructors, instance methods, and
>   instance accessors.

In your example, `this.doSomething()` refers to a method in some arbitrary class outside of that method. `this` is redundant.

It is useful to use `this` in cases like this:

```
public Employee(string name, string alias) 
{
   this.name = name;
   this.alias = alias;
}
```

It helps delineate between the meaning. Otherwise, without `this` what `name` or `alias` are you really referring to?

Finally, `sender` is going to refer to the `object` which raised the event.